# Converting literal Chars to Word8

Tags: haskell, ghc, bytestring

The documentation for [ByteString](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/bytestring-0.10.0.2/Data-ByteString.html#v:breakByte) gives the following code example:

```
breakByte :: Word8 -> ByteString -> (ByteString, ByteString)
breakByte 'c' "abcd"
```

However when I write the same I get the following error [(ideone)](http://ideone.com/q7TYqD):

```
Couldn't match expected type `GHC.Word.Word8'
            with actual type `Char'
```

Of course `'c'` is a `Char`, not `Word8`. Presumably they're using some extension which allows a `fromInteger` style function to work automatically on `Char` literals, but I'm not sure what. `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 6):

Just import [the Char8 versions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.9.2.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html) of the modules. These do the byte conversions. Note that this is for 8 bit characters. So don't try putting unicode data into it.